# put data in tbody from fetch api

Tags: javascript, html-table, fetch, fetch-api, html-tbody

Hello i want to put data from api in table's tbody but when i use below code.
It is created one tbody tag for each data .
I want all the data to be in one tbody tag.
how can i do ?

```
fetch(get_data)
.then(function (response) {
    response.text().then(function (responseText) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(responseText);



        obj.forEach(user => {
            const markup = `

                    <td class="customer" id="company${user.id}">${user.company}</td>
                    <td class="customer" id="first_name${user.id}">${user.first_name}</td>
                    <td class="customer" id="last_name${user.id}">${user.last_name}</td>
                
            


            `;
            document.querySelector("thead").insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', markup);




        });





    });





});
```

[image: image of code when use the]

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
document.querySelector("thead").insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', markup);
```

to

```
document.querySelector("tbody").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);
```